# Stop and clear a function from executing on a button click

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code to prevent users from going back using the browsers back arrow. I want to exclude this on a specific page where the user is previewing a PDF. Please help how to stop this on button click. Thanks.

I have tried using event listeners but, it is not working.

This is the function to prevent user from going back

```
//Prevent the user from going back 

function preventBack() {
  window.history.forward();
}
setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);

window.onunload = function() {
  null
};
```

This is the code I introduced for event listeners to stop the function on button click.

```
//Prevent the user from going back 

function preventBack(event) {
  window.history.forward();
  var x = document.getElementById("pdf");
  x.addEventListener("click", function() {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    clearTimeout(sam);
  });
}
var sam = setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);

window.onunload = function() {
  null
};
```

When the user has previewed the PDF, they should be able to get back to the profile.

Comment: It is horrifically poor UX to block people from using the browser chrome. You need to fix the reason you are trying to block them. For example using location.replace to remove a URL from the history. Also I can long-click on the back button to navigate to the page your are trying to protect anyway

Comment: It is a bad idea to remove functionality that a user expects to have from their browser.

Comment: I am just using it for security reasons.

Comment: You are not offering *any* security with this.

Comment: There are no security reasons that are solved with your code

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. Let me try using that method.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but never pass a string to `setTimeout`, write `setTimeout(preventBack, 0);` instead. Using strings introduce various problems, and prevents correct linting and code minification.